# Transform datas in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, pivot

I've got a query like this

```sql
select company, extract(week from date) as week, sum(value) 
from temporary GROUP BY company,yearweek(date)
```

and after I got a view

```
Company       | Week  | Value 
Dunaferr      |   1   | 310        
Dunaferr      |   2   | 220        
Dunaferr      |   3   | 310
Pentele-Invest|   1   | 450
Pentele-Invest|   2   | 543
Pentele-Invest|   3   | 344
```

Finally what I want to is a table which one is sums the values weekly which is ordered by the company names

```
company_name | week1 | week2  | week3 | week4 ...
dunaferr     | 35000 | 36000  | 28000 | 3411
pentele      | 34000 | 255000 | 3341  | 3433
```

And I know there is a way to use pivoting but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
select  szallito_nev,
sum(case extract(week from beerkezes_datuma) when '1' then merlegelt_suly else 0 end) as 'Het 1',
sum(case extract(week from beerkezes_datuma) when '2' then merlegelt_suly else 0 end) as 'Het 2',
sum(case extract(week from beerkezes_datuma) when '3' then merlegelt_suly else 0 end) as 'Het 3',
    from 2013_backup GROUP BY szallito_nev with rollup;
```

i'll tried this one its work well but not so elegant way to do it:S becouse i have to go throw all the weeks of the year. probably theres a way to do it with loop